# Select random rows but without duplicates of values from another column

Tags: mysql, sql, random

I have the following query which gives me 3 random names,ids and top_tags:

```
SELECT  Name
     , id
     , top_tag 
  FROM artists 
 WHERE  not find_in_set (id,'1,2,3,4') 
 order 
    by rand() 
 limit 3
```

It works fine, however, I do need another condition.
I have a column name `top_tag` (int), I need that the result will include 3 unique `top_tag` values and not duplicates of `top_tag`.

Comment: What is `not find_in_set()` supposed to be doing?  Have you ever heard of `not in`?

Comment: @Strawberry Updated, thanks. when copying the query from C# it was removed. note that `not find_in_set()` is not really related to the question, but I just use it in the query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff `not in` would also work. `find_in_set` is pretty similar to what you are referring.  [link]https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

Comment: Similar in result, but `FIND_IN_SET()` won't use an index, whereas `NOT IN()` will.

Comment: @BillKarwin Noted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL 8+, you would use window functions:

```
SELECT Name, id, top_tag 
FROM (SELECT a.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY top_tag ORDER BY rand()) as seqnum
      FROM artists a
      WHERE id NOT IN (1, 2, 3, 4) 
     ) a
WHERE seqnum = 1
LIMIT 3;
```

Comment: Does the LIMIT preserve the randomness, or our some rows more likely to be excluded than others?

Comment: the `a.*` needs to be changed for `*` for the query to work.

Comment: @Strawberry . . . Random rows are random rows.  If you take the first <n>, that is a random sample.  So is the last <n> or, in fact, any <n> chosen independently of the values in the row.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Gordon's answer, but this may ensure three distinct and random top_tags:

```
SELECT Name, id, top_tag
FROM (
    SELECT name, id, top_tag, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY top_tag ORDER BY RAND()) AS seqnum
    FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT top_tag FROM artists 
      WHERE id NOT IN (1,2,3,4) 
      ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3) AS t
    JOIN artists AS a ON (t.top_tag = a.top_tag)
    WHERE a.id NOT IN (1,2,3,4)
) AS x
WHERE seqnum = 1
```

Or you could just stick with your original query, but increase the sample size:

```
SELECT Name, id, top_tag 
FROM artists 
WHERE id NOT IN (1,2,3,4)
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 30
```

Then in your app, fetch more results until you have three rows with distinct `top_tag` values, discarding rows with any `top_tag` values you've already fetched. If you get through all 30 and still haven't gotten three distinct tags, just try again (but be careful not to re-try indefinitely, because that'll cause an infinite loop if your data doesn't include more than two distinct top_tag values).